# After upgrade to 4.7.6(and 4.7.7) - Freezes on "estimating" when loading group into Email, when working with groups in general

Tags: email, error

We have a serious problem after upgrading to 4.7.6 and now to 4.7.7 (without solving the problem) - it is a problem that seems to have been active already in previous version (other people posted about it in 2015), but i can´t find a clue to solve it.
See here a post to this topic from somebody from 2015: 
https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16277

It is even impossible to access certain groups (the screen freezes and I manually need to kill the processes /on sleep / in the control panel)

It works when I create a new group with 1 person, but I need to work with
groups with approx. 4000 people.

It also seems that sometimes it goes through, but most of the time it freezes and it´s impossible to work.

Please if you have the same problem or know a solution, please let us know.
[image]

Attached an excerpt from our slow log file

## Query 1: 0.02 QPS, 0.15x concurrency, ID 0x59955E428CD5C6B0 at byte 18602444

## Scores: V/M = 8.80

## Time range: 2016-05-11 11:19:48 to 23:54:11

## Attribute    pct   total     min     max     avg     95%  stddev  median

## ============ === ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= =======

## Count         12     795

## Exec time     42   6812s   188ms     49s      9s     26s      9s      5s

## Lock time     17      5s     2ms      2s     6ms     8ms    63ms     3ms

## Rows sent      0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0

## Rows examine  67   2.30G   8.59k  28.24M   2.96M  27.20M   6.75M 270.35k

## Rows affecte   2   7.43M       0  53.07k   9.57k  44.45k  13.14k   3.35k

## Bytes sent     0  41.69k       0      79   53.70   54.21    8.93   54.21

## Query size    19 782.95k    1006    1009 1008.48  964.41       0  964.41

## String:

## Databases    gemeingut_civicrm

## Hosts        localhost

## Last errno   0 (772/97%), 1160 (22/2%), 1213 (1/0%)

## Users        gemeingut

## Query_time distribution

## 1us

## 10us

## 100us

## 1ms

## 10ms

## 100ms

## 1s

## 10s+

## Tables

## SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM `gemeingut_civicrm` LIKE 'civicrm_contact'

## SHOW CREATE TABLE `gemeingut_civicrm`.`civicrm_contact`

## SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM `gemeingut_civicrm` LIKE 'civicrm_group_contact_cache'

## SHOW CREATE TABLE `gemeingut_civicrm`.`civicrm_group_contact_cache`

## SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM `gemeingut_civicrm` LIKE 'civicrm_group_contact'

## SHOW CREATE TABLE `gemeingut_civicrm`.`civicrm_group_contact`

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE civicrm_temp_group_contact_cache186 (SELECT 184 as group_id,  contact_a.id as id  FROM civicrm_contact contact_a  LEFT JOIN civicrm_group_contact_cache `civicrm_group_contact_cache_111` ON contact_a.id = `civicrm_group_contact_cache_111`.contact_id    LEFT JOIN civicrm_group_contact_cache `civicrm_group_contact_cache_30` ON contact_a.id = `civicrm_group_contact_cache_30`.contact_id    LEFT JOIN civicrm_group_contact_cache `civicrm_group_contact_cache_8` ON contact_a.id = `civicrm_group_contact_cache_8`.contact_id   WHERE  (  ( `civicrm_group_contact_cache_30`.group_id = 30 )  OR  ( `civicrm_group_contact_cache_111`.group_id = 111 )  OR  ( `civicrm_group_contact_cache_8`.group_id = 8 )  )  AND (contact_a.is_deleted = 0)   AND contact_a.id NOT IN (
                              SELECT contact_id FROM civicrm_group_contact
                              WHERE civicrm_group_contact.status = 'Removed'
                              AND   civicrm_group_contact.group_id = 184 ) )

## Converted for EXPLAIN

## EXPLAIN /*!50100 PARTITIONS*/

SELECT 184 as group_id,  contact_a.id as id  FROM civicrm_contact contact_a  LEFT JOIN civicrm_group_contact_cache `civicrm_group_contact_cache_111` ON contact_a.id = `civicrm_group_contact_cache_111`.contact_id    LEFT JOIN civicrm_group_contact_cache `civicrm_group_contact_cache_30` ON contact_a.id = `civicrm_group_contact_cache_30`.contact_id    LEFT JOIN civicrm_group_contact_cache `civicrm_group_contact_cache_8` ON contact_a.id = `civicrm_group_contact_cache_8`.contact_id   WHERE  (  ( `civicrm_group_contact_cache_30`.group_id = 30 )  OR  ( `civicrm_group_contact_cache_111`.group_id = 111 )  OR  ( `civicrm_group_contact_cache_8`.group_id = 8 )  )  AND (contact_a.is_deleted = 0)   AND contact_a.id NOT IN (
                              SELECT contact_id FROM civicrm_group_contact
                              WHERE civicrm_group_contact.status = 'Removed'
                              AND   civicrm_group_contact.group_id = 184 ) )

Comment: We saw a similar issue in 4.6.4. Happened when we excluded or included more than a couple of groups in a mailing. Haven't seen it just trying to load one group. Our poor mans workaround was to do all of our excludes first in search builder / custom search and just load one group into the mailing. Seems to have gotten much rarer / possibly gone since upgrading to 4.7.13.

Answer (score 1):

We had similar issues in 4.6.x, see https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17213. Let me know if you think this could be related to your problem.